# How can I retrieve the input values of dynamically created textfields?

Tags: c#, arrays, winforms, dynamic, textbox

Here is my code so far where I have a numericupdown item named numericUpDown and button. Once the user selects a number when they press the button it dynamically created the fields.

```
private void createPerson_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{    
    Label[] person_Name = new Label[(int)this.numericUpDown.Value];
    TextBox[] person_txtinput = new TextBox[(int)this.numericUpDown.Value];

    for (int i = 0; i < this.numericUpDown.Value; i++)
    {    
        //create person name label 
        Person_Name[i] = new Label();
        Person_Name[i].Location = new System.Drawing.Point(20, 114 + i * 25);
        Person_Name[i].Size = new System.Drawing.Size(120, 15);
        Person_Name[i].Text = (i + 1).ToString() + @")" + "Person Name:";
        this.Controls.Add(Person_Name[i]);

        //create person name textbox
        PersonNameTxtInput[i] = new TextBox();
        PersonNameTxtInput[i].Location = new System.Drawing.Point(140, 114 + i * 25);
        PersonNameTxtInput[i].Size = new System.Drawing.Size(125, 20);
        this.Controls.Add(PersonNameTxtInput[i]);    
    }    
}



 private void save_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    for (int i = 0; j < this.numericUpDown.Value; i++)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("" + PersonNameTxtInput[i].Text);
    }
}
```

My question is, how can I get all the values from the textboxes depending on how many fields are created by the user when the save button is pressed?

I have tried using the code within the save button listener however how can i make `Label[] person_Name = new Label[(int)this.numericUpDown.Value];` a global variable so i can access it within the save button for loop.

Comment: Is there a reason you can't just iterate through this.Controls?

Comment: Could u expand on your question im quite new to coding. If i iterate through this.Controls wouldnt i also be getting the label names.                                  I just need the value from text field and not the label. Here is some code i wrote.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, I don't know exactly why you are doing this in this particular way and I must admit it doesn't seem very effective, but you could just do what Ryan_L suggested and iterate through this.Controls like this

```
for(int i = 0; i < this.Controls.Count; i++)
{
    if(this.Controls[i] is TextBox) //skip buttons and labels
    {
        MessageBox.Show("" + this.Controls[i].Text);
    }
}
```

Now, regarding your question *how to define a global variable so you can access it within the save button for loop*...just define the two arrays outside of the **createPerson_Click** event like this:

```
Label[] person_Name;
TextBox[] person_txtinput;

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    person_Name = new Label[(int)this.numericUpDown.Value];
    person_txtinput = new TextBox[(int)this.numericUpDown.Value];
    //the rest of the code
}
```

Hope this helps. However, you might want to reconsider your entire approach.

Comment: hey i have tried your method and it works however is there a way to a specific group of text fields. for example if a user selects 2 from the numericupdown field therefore creating the fields persons name , person surname twice, how would i store each value within a variable.                                        The purpose of this is that I need to get the input from the user and save into an xml file.

Comment: I am not sure I understood the question correctly, but if I did understand it, you could just store each value to a list of strings. So, instead of MessageBox.Show, you'd have something like this:

`myList.Add(this.Controls[i].Text);`

Then, after the for loop, you could just serialize the list. See [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/0a5aa658-7276-42e5-9d9e-b786694d6020/c-serialize-liststring-to-xml?forum=csharpgeneral) thread to learn how to serialize a list.

Comment: i managed to do it with the my method seems i was specifying the wrong location for the data to be saved in ;s . Thanks for the help